# Failed to read VM '[Empty Name]' OVF, it may be corrupted

Tags: kvm-virtualization, physical-to-virtual, rhev, ovirt

When importing a VM from virt-p2v into rhev/ovirt, I am greeted with a `Failed to read VM '[Empty Name]' OVF, it may be corrupted` when I visit the `VM import` tab. The `engine.log` gives this unhelpful descriptor: `Error parsing OVF due to 2`.

The virt-p2v process ran fine and said it was successful - what gives?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when `<DefaultDisplayType>` had a value of `2`. Changing it to be a value of `1` removed the error message and showed the VM in the `VM Import` tab.

REF:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1261951 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1261281